# Getting weird error trying to connect to remote sql anywhere db with node-sqlanywhere

Tags: sql, database, node.js, sqlanywhere

I'm trying to connect to a remote Sql Anywhere 12.01 database with the following code:

```
    let sqlanywhere = require('sqlanywhere');

    let conn = sqlanywhere.createConnection();


    let conn_params = {
        Server : 'server:port',
        UserId : 'user',
        Password : 'pass'
    };

    conn.connect(conn_params, function() {
        console.log("Connected!");
        conn.exec('select * from cases', function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }

        });
    });
```

My console.log("Connected!") fires so I'm assuming that I've connected to the remote database? However, any query that I make results in this:

```
[Error: Code: -2001 Msg: Invalid Object]
```

I looked through the error codes online and didn't find this one. Anyone know why I may be experiencing it and how I can fix it?

Comment: Don't you have to select a database first?

Comment: No idea. My DBA just said that I can connect to the database at a particular public facing IP:Port. My code is basically the exact code from the node-sqlanywhere readme.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function should take two parameters: err and result. If err is undefined, then the connection succeeded, otherwise it indicates what error occurred. (In the case of connection, result will always be undefined.) Your code should look like this:

```
...
conn.connect( conn_params, function( err, result ) {
   if( err ) {
      console.log( "Connection failed: "+err );
   } else {
      console.log( "Connected!" );
   }
   ...
});
```

I had to change "let" to "var" to make the javascript run. Also, your Server connection parameter should be the server name, not the location. You should change "Server" to "Host" to indicate the hostname / port.

*Note: This answer was copied from the same question posted on [sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com](http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/25779/getting-weird-error-with-node-sqlanywhere).*